# Ajv not defined in Jest test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ajv

I want to test my class with jest. This class is importing ajv.js 6.12.2 and the test fails on that. So what i basicly did is:

1. Add `export default Ajv` statement to the end of the ajv.js
2. Import ajv.js with `import Ajv from './lib/ajv.js'`
3. Add `"transform": {"^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"}` to package.json
4. Created babel.json and insert
   `{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"], "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"] }`

When I run the test with `npm test` I get the following error:

ReferenceError: Ajv is not defined

```
    > 4 | export default Ajv;`
```

When I run the script in browser Ajv could be used normally.
Can anybody give me a hint what to do?

Comment: You modified the source code of an installed package (ajv)?

Comment: Yes, shame on me but i want to use the ajv in the browser and i didn't find an other way to import the Ajv module.

Comment: No shame, just trying to understand. But why do you need to do this? Aren't you using a bundler such as webpack or parcel?

Comment: Did not thought about using one of them. My normal workflow was to get the js, store it locally and import it over src tag. But now i need lib's in the js file itself.